# If a flight crew becomes incapacitated some way, in space, can they still get home?

Tags: spacecraft, rescue-missions

How would a crew of a spacecraft get home if 'everyone' on the spacecraft becomes incapacitated, immobilized or go unconscious?

The crew is alive and stable but unable to operate equipment.

Is there automation in the system that can be invoked in a contingency? Can operators from the ground remote control the space craft back to earth? What about the reentry stage?

They could have suffered from some form of paralysis, or experienced an event that knocks them out or something else happened via poison, bacteria or virus.

Comment: Interesting question, but very broad. Could you narrow it down to a single spacecraft, or single type of spacecraft? There are simply too many possibilities to provide an answer as it stands.

Comment: @ForgeMonkey I think I am most curious on the possibilities. I am sure there are one or two people familiar with particular equipment or instances where things like this were considered or an actual event required non-crew members to activate and do something that was touch and go (so to speak).

Comment: At the very least, you have to specify the type of spacecraft. Capability for remote control is VASTLY different between various current and historical types (STS, Apollo, Gemini, Shenzhou, Soyuz, Vostok/Voskhod...).

Comment: @DeerHunter Ok, updated the question to address the concerns about spacecraft type.

Comment: As I recall the autopilot could land the STS (sans undercarrage) but couldn't control the vehicle in space. However, I remember something about a cable being designed after the Columbia disaster that would connect the flight controls to the autopilot so that the whole thing could be controlled from the ground. I can't find any references though, so I might be misremembering.

Comment: Aha! I was right, see Andy's answer below.

Comment: In your question's title, you're speculating about possible future events, but in your question's body you then narrow the answer set down to STS. That's fairly inconsistent considering that STS won't ever fly again. I'd suggest editing the title to reflect your actual question. Perhaps _"If Space Shuttle crew became incapacitated, could mission control have safely landed them?"_ ;)

Comment: @TildalWave Sorry boss, they were twisting my arm to pick something. I had to do something. I didn't want to add STS or any spacecraft at all. Because that excludes everything else.  Like my other questions I like the broad range because it pulls people with some interesting perspectives and a few surprise answers that have me curious about the Author of the answer...Like he might be a direct knowledge source. Ya know?

Comment: @tidalwave Alright I am decoupling STS from this question.

Comment: @FrankTudor That then again makes it too broad and invalidates the answer you already got. I'd suggest simply reflecting in the title your actual question, and rather ask a new one (you can link to this one if it helps provide context) if you wanted to know something else. Note that other contributors aren't required to follow-up on the changes you make to the question itself. In fact, they're not even notified of that unless they favorited it and check for updates in their profile.

Comment: @TildalWave I did a semi-edit ...I think your link slipped out.

Comment: @Tidalwave Nah, its ok, it hasn't got too much airplay. I am about to tweet it so it should get some fresh eyes. (Qualified it too, so Andy's answer is still valid in context).

Comment: @FrankTudor That's not the point. The point is that if the question is too broad to answer, it'll be closed. There's many different crewed spacecraft that fly or have flown to space, each of them with differently autonomous systems, or an altogether different landing system. E.g. there was a case, sadly fatal for crew of three, where the Soyuz capsule landed safely in Kazakhstan but the crew was later found to be dead inside (suffocated). It's just an example, perhaps not the most cheerful one, but it should make a case against asking too broad questions. Surely you don't want vague answers.

Comment: @TildalWave Soyuz and Kazakhstan...I vaguely remember that.  That would make for an excellent answer if ground control was involved in helping them...I wish you could add that as an Answer with the details.  Ok, well I do want to get a broader set of answers and examples just like yours but I don't want to get shut down.  Let me think on this and fix it.

Comment: Please note that we're a Q&A and refer to our [About] and [Help] for more information on how we function, more specifically in your case our [Ask] page. Say, for example, that I posted another answer that could be equally correct like the one you already got but describing a different spacecraft and space agency. Should we put two such answers to popularity vote which one is better? And which one would you accept as the one answering your question then? You see the conundrum here? So we strive to ask questions that can identify best and most complete answer. Yours, currently, can't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to 2006, STS could not be landed via Mission Control. The [landing gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_orbiter#Landing_gear) could only be operated manually.

After the *Columbia* accident, the rest of the fleet was refitted with the [RCO IFM cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-3xx#Remote_Control_Orbiter), a 28-foot braided cable that the flight crew could use to link the cockpit with the shuttle's avionics bay and give Mission Control access to the appropriate switches.

Comment: And for what it's worth, the Soviet Union's Buran shuttle was remotely piloted for its entire journey, including the landing (it was only ever launched one, unmanned). It should be pretty easy to find out about Soyuz - I know the retro-rockets automatically fire a meter or so above the ground, but I'm not 100% about the parachute.